# Disabling iCloud Drive sync on specific Wifi networks

Tags: icloud, high-sierra

Is there a way to do this ? I have disabled iCloud Drive for certain directories by adding `.nosync` to it's name but this situation is different. Maybe using monitoring the wifi network SSID and launching a custom command.

Comment: Why? This just seems unusual.

Comment: On rare occasions the wifi I connect to is via a 4G router so I would like to disable iCloud Drive sync when that happens.

Comment: On rare occasions the wifi I connect to is via a 4G router so I would like to disable iCloud Drive sync when that happens.

Answer (score 1):

Try [TripMode.](https://www.tripmode.ch/) It's a third party app, but it's build to do exactly what you want. There's a free trial as well.

> TripMode activates itself on networks where you’ve turned it on before. Set it, then forget it.